# Android Loading Strings into Array

Tags: android, arrays, string, text, load

I have a list of 1000 words. I need to load an array with n randomly chosen words from that list (no repeats allowed).  What is the best way of going about doing that?

My ideas:

1) Load the words into R.arrays to create a String array. Use collections.shuffle to shuffle the array, then pull the first n entries from it. Right now, I am having memory issues loading the initial array with the 1000 words using this method.

2) Load the words into a text file, read each word into a String array. Use same method to get first n entries.

3) Hard code the input of the words into a String array (I'd use a script to get that output of course). Use same method to get first n entries.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If you're mainly worried about memory usage and you're willing to give up computation speed, here's an algorithm that will get you there.

Keep your words in a text file, one word per line, with a fixed amount of characters per word, padding each word with spaces at the end to ensure a fixed word char size, call it `s`.

1. Create an array of max size `n`, call it `w`
2. Open a stream reader to the file containing the 1000 words
3. Get a random number between 1 and 1000, call it `k`
4. Seek to position `k*s` in the file stream and grab the next `s` characters
5. Add the word to `w` if it does not exist in the array yet
6. If the `w` array is full (ie. size=`n`), we're done, otherwise go back to step 3

Let us know how it goes. Happy coding!

Comment: That seems just crazy enough to work. Any idea why Android complains when I just load the strings directly from R.arrays? Do 1000 strings really take up that much memory?

Comment: Yes Strings are quite expensive. When memory is a concern I'd stay away from them as much as possible.